# How to find the basis of kernel?

Tags: linear-algebra

[image: Homework Question]
I am having trouble with how to do this question. I know how to find the basis of the image of the matrix. However, I'm not quite sure how he got the answer for the basis of kernel.

\begin{bmatrix} -1&-1&-1\\    1&0&1 \\ -1&-1&-2  \end{bmatrix}

and I also have tried

\begin{bmatrix} -1&1&-1\\    -1&0&-1 \\ -1&1&-2  \end{bmatrix}

and I got this for both

\begin{bmatrix} 1&0&0\\    0&1&0 \\ 0&0&1  \end{bmatrix}

I don't know how to do the question. please any help?

Comment: Do you know how to find a general expression for $T$? In this case, you can simply solve $Tx = 0$ and pick representatives. Do you know how to find a matrix representation for $T$, and how to find the kernel of a matrix? That could be another approach.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri Not quite sure what you are talking about, can you give me an example or something?

Comment: Do you know what a kernel is?

Comment: @ Fimpellizieri suppose A is the matrix then Av = 0 so I'm guessing that we need to find v?

Comment: The equation $Av = 0$ is related to the kernel, but you should try and organize the thoughts in your head. What *is* the kernel of $A$?

Comment: @Fimpellizieri What do you mean? I know the definitely of A? I don't quite understand how to set up the matrix. Did a set the matrix correctly?

Comment: What are these matrices that you’re manipulating? The domain of $T$ is three-dimensional and its codomain is four-dimensional, so if you’re trying to create a matrix that represents $T$, it should be $4\times3$.

Answer (score 1):

HINT.- Note $e_1=-x^2-x-1\hspace{10mm} e_2=x^2+1\hspace{10mm} e_3=-x^2-x-2\hspace{10mm}A=\begin{pmatrix}5&1\\1&2\end{pmatrix}$

We have $T(e_1)=-3A\hspace{10mm}T(e_2)=2A\hspace{10mm}T(e_3)=-4A$

It follows that the dimension of $T(P_2)=1$ and can be generated by the matrix $A$.
Now if $v=ae_1+be_2+ce_3$ is in the kernel then $$T(v)=\begin{pmatrix}-15a+10b-20c&-3a+2b-4c\\-3a+2b-4c&-6a+4b-8c\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$$ which reduces to the only equation $$-3a+2b-4c=0$$ In other words $$v=ae_1+be_2+ce_3\in T^{-1}\left(\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}\right)\iff-3a+2b-4c=0$$
What more?